# Cannot find name error in VSCode React Typescript Component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, react-component

I have a component in react that I am currently trying to use in building a project. Am new to react so not exactly sure what I am doing, am also trying to use typescript for this project. In creating a component I am getting this error:

[image]

Actual code for InputField is:

```
const InputField = () => {
return (
    <form className="input">
        <input type="input" placeholder="Enter ID" className='input__box'></input>
        <input type="input" placeholder="Enter PW" className='input__box'></input>
        <button className='input__submit' type='submit'>Enter</button>
    </form>
)
```

}

Not exactly sure what is wrong. Followed [this post](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-typescript-cannot-find-name#:%7E:text=To%20solve%20the%20%22Cannot%20find,types%20packages%20for%20your%20application.) which directly relates to this issue but it did not help at all.

Have other people working on this project, and there are no red squiggles for them.

Have tried to uninstall all extensions, did not help.

Here is the ts.config file:

`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!